# Sorting array of string but numbers last

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i need to sort my array. I'd like to see string starting/containing numbers after alfa.

As:

`['ip', 'email', '0email', 'em0ail' ,1001, '23name', 'name', 'address']`

should be:

`['address', 'email', 'em0ail', 'ip', 'name', '0email', 1001, '23name']`

So `0` should be after `z`

```
columns.sort((a, b) => {
      const x = a.toString();
      const y = b.toString();
      if (x < y) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (x > y) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
```

returns numbers first

How should i approach this case? Do i have to iterate through whole string?

Comment: Split the original array in two arrays: startWithLetter and startWithNumber. Sort them individually and merge the arrays as you want.

Comment: @EliasSoares seems like too much work, rather than just checking the start of each item during sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do i have to iterate through whole string?

Not if you're just basing this on the first character in the string (as you seem to, with `em0ail` being sorted with the strings). Just check whether the strings start with a digit or a non-digit, and in cases where one has a digit but the other doesn't, return the appropriate 1 or -1 to put the non-digit one first; in cases where they both do or don't start with a digit, return the result of `localeCompare`.

(For the one that's a number, we can just convert to string.)

```js
const columns = ['ip', 'email', '0email', 'em0ail' ,1001, '23name', 'name', 'address'];

function startsWithDigit(v) {
    const ch = v[0];
    return ch >= "0" && ch <= "9";
}

columns.sort((a, b) => {
    a = String(a);
    b = String(b);
    adigit = startsWithDigit(a);
    bdigit = startsWithDigit(b);
    if (adigit == bdigit) {
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    } else if (adigit) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
});

console.log(columns);
```

Comment: An alternative for `startsWithDigit` implementation is to do a `parseInt` and check if the result is `NaN`. Started writing an answer where this was basically the only major difference but no need to now, so I'm leaving it as a comment.

Comment: @VLAZ - That would be simpler, wouldn't it? Good idea.

Comment: Hmm, I thought of a (potential) problem with `parseInt` - spaces at the start. The string `"  123abc"` will be parsed to `123`. I don't know if OP expects that to be the case (space is ignored) or not.

Comment: That's fair enough. `parseInt` is a possible approach but without knowing the requirements here it's hard to say if it's correct. It does seem a bit inconsistent, though, since `" a"` and `"b"` would be sorted differently to `" 1"` and `"2"`.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>


<script>
var columns=['ip', 'email', '0email', 'em0ail' ,1001, '23name', 'name', 'address'];
function Turn(CharZ){
 //Make 0~9 biger then a-z and A-Z
 if(CharZ<'9'.charCodeAt()){
  return CharZ+'Z'.charCodeAt();
 }
 return CharZ;
}
columns.sort((a, b) => {
 var x = a.toString();
 var y = b.toString();
 var Lx=x.length;
 var Ly=y.length;
 var MinL=Math.min(Lx, Ly);
 for (var i = 0; i < MinL; i++) {
  if(Turn(x.charCodeAt(i))-Turn(y.charCodeAt(i))>0){
   return 1;
  }else if(Turn(x.charCodeAt(i))-Turn(y.charCodeAt(i))<0){
   return -1;
  }
  
  
 }
 //if front all equals  but length not same mean there is remain
 if (Lx > Ly) {
  return 1;
 }
 if (Lx < Ly) {
  return -1;
 }
 return 0;
});
document.body.innerHTML = columns;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this help