# Sort alphanumeric strings - Letters first

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, alphanumeric

```
var List = ["F", "60", "59", "6", "7", "7'", "60'", "60a", "c1", "A", "5", "a1", "6.2", "A'", "B", "A1"];

var sortedListe = List.sort(function (a, b) {
  var collator = new Intl.Collator('en', { numeric: true, sensitivity: "base" });
  return collator.compare(a, b);
});

console.log(sortedListe);
```

What I get: ["5", "6", "6.2", "7", "7'", "59", "60", "60'", "60a", "A", "A'", "a1", "A1", "B", "c1", "F"]

https://jsfiddle.net/5coraw0z/

**PRO**: 6.2 comes before 7; 7' is also in the right place; c1 is between B and F.
**CONTRA**: Strings beginning with a letter are at the end of the list.

My expected result: ["A", "A'", "a1", "A1", "B", "c1", "F", "5", "6", "6.2", "7", "7'", "59", "60", "60'", "60a"]

Comment: strings beginning with numbers are always sorted before those beginning with letters in alphabetic sorting. Your order is non-normative so you'll need to write your own comparator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting array of string but numbers last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56851321/sorting-array-of-string-but-numbers-last)

Comment: You can introduce this _additional code_ to get the result (but the solution doesn't use a single comparator). `var ix = sortedListe.findIndex(e => /^[a-zA-Z()]+$/.test(e.charAt(0))); 
var result = sortedListe.slice(ix).concat(sortedListe.splice(0, ix));`

Comment: btw, what order do you expect for values like `['6.2', '6.10']`? the used collator separates by dots and changing of alpha/numerical characters. if you like to sort by numerical value, the order is different.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340227/sort-mixed-alpha-numeric-array Has ideas, not exact match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need non-standard sorting rules, it's often easier to sort each part of the array separately rather than inventing a convoluted sorting callback:

```js
function partition(ary, fn) {
    let res = [[], []]
    for (let x of ary)
        res[fn(x) ? 1 : 0].push(x)
    return res
}

let List = ["F", "60", "59", "6", "7", "7'", "60'", "60a", "c1", "A", "5", "a1", "6.2", "A'", "B", "A1"];

let collator = new Intl.Collator('en', { numeric: true, sensitivity: "base" });

let sortedListe = [].concat(
  ...partition(List, x => !isNaN(x[0]))
    .map(a => a.sort(collator.compare)))

console.log(...sortedListe);
```

Comment: I agree partitioning can be useful, but you've already defined the extra sorting condition so it could just be `List.sort((a, b) => { ... return !isNaN(a[0]) - !isNaN(b[0]) || collator.compare(a, b)})` (which is just a refinement of the duplicate)

Comment: isNaN(' ') === false

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev that is also covered in the duplicate, but the OPs sample data has no strings starting with space.

Answer (score 2):

With this kind of data we could avoid the collator. The logic is to sort the items char by char with fetching as much as possible digit chars. At first sight it could look complicated, but that's just char by char comparison with alpha/numeric/undefined cases.

The goal was speed, to avoid any intermediate arrays like in the gog's soluiton.

There's also an important difference that the gog's solution splits everything into 2 alpha and numeric strings to compare. While my solution accept any number of alpha/numeric strings combined.

```js
const list = ["F", "60", "59", "6", "7", "7'", "60a", "60'", "c1", "A", "5", "a1", "6.2", "A'", "B", "A1"];

// fetch as much as possible digits from a position in a string plus adjust the position
const gainNum = (str, idx) => {
  let num = '';
  for(;idx < str.length; idx++){
    const c = str[idx];
    if( c < '0' || c > '9' ) break;
    num += c;
  }
  return {num, idx};
}

function sort(aa, bb, ai = 0, bi = 0) {

  // compare numbers
  let anum, bnum;
  ({num: anum, idx: ai} = gainNum(aa, ai));
  ({num: bnum, idx: bi} = gainNum(bb, bi));

  if(anum) return bnum ? anum - bnum || sort(aa, bb, ai, bi) : 1; else if(bnum) return -1;

  // compare string lengths
  if(ai===aa.length) return  bi < bb.length ? -1 : 0; else if(bi === bb.length) return 1;

  // compare alpha chars
  let a = aa[ai].toLowerCase();
  let b = bb[bi].toLowerCase();
  return a === b ? sort(aa, bb, ai + 1, bi + 1) : a > b ? 1 : -1;
}

console.log('expected:', ...["A", "A'", "a1", "A1", "B", "c1", "F", "5", "6", "6.2", "7", "7'", "59", "60", "60'", "60a"]);

console.log('sorted  :', ...list.slice().sort(sort));
```

```
` Chrome/118
------------------------------------------------------
Alexander   1.00x  |  x100000  150  156  182  188  190
gog         4.40x  |  x100000  660  665  666  670  672
------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const list = ["F", "60", "59", "6", "7", "7'", "60a", "60'", "c1", "A", "5", "a1", "6.2", "A'", "B", "A1"];

// @benchmark gog

function partition(ary, fn) {
    let res = [[], []]
    for (let x of ary)
        res[fn(x) ? 1 : 0].push(x)
    return res
}

let collator = new Intl.Collator('en', { numeric: true, sensitivity: "base" });

[].concat(
  ...partition(list, x => !isNaN(x[0]))
    .map(a => a.sort(collator.compare)))

// @benchmark Alexander

// fetch as much as possible digits from a position in a string plus adjust the position
const gainNum = (str, idx) => {
  let num = '';
  for(;idx < str.length; idx++){
    const c = str[idx];
    if( c < '0' || c > '9' ) break;
    num += c;
  }
  return {num, idx};
}

function sort(aa, bb, ai = 0, bi = 0) {

  // compare numbers
  let anum, bnum;
  ({num: anum, idx: ai} = gainNum(aa, ai));
  ({num: bnum, idx: bi} = gainNum(bb, bi));

  if(anum) return bnum ? anum - bnum || sort(aa, bb, ai, bi) : 1; else if(bnum) return -1;

  // compare string lengths
  if(ai===aa.length) return  bi < bb.length ? -1 : 0; else if(bi === bb.length) return 1;

  // compare alpha chars
  let a = aa[ai].toLowerCase();
  let b = bb[bi].toLowerCase();
  return a === b ? sort(aa, bb, ai + 1, bi + 1) : a > b ? 1 : -1;
}


list.slice().sort(sort);

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Comment: So complicated...

Comment: @epascarello maybe at first sight but really it's just sorting char by char, nothing extremely complicated

Comment: @epascarello the goal was speed

Comment: The benefit of the collator is widespread character support across languages. Put an accented character in`"ā1"`.

Comment: @pilchard agree, for alpha chars we could utilize the collator anyway

Answer (score 0):

A representation function `repr` and a `TrueSet` implementing `representation-based` equivalences among objects (see the [@ut8pia/classifier](https://github.com/ut8pia/classifier/) library) can immediatly provide the expected order.

After posing:

```
const 
    data = ["F", "60", "59", "6", "7", "7'", "60'", "60a", "c1", "A", ...],
    expected = ["A", "A'", "a1", "A1", "B", "c1", "F", "5", "6", "6.2", ...],
    collator = new Intl.Collator('en', { 
        numeric: true, 
        sensitivity: 'case', 
        caseFirst: 'lower'
    })
```

the items are added to a `TrueSet`:

```
const
    repr = item => [Number.parseInt(item[0] + 1)? 1: 0],
    set = TrueSet.of(repr, ORDER.ASCENDING, collator.compare.bind(collator))
        .letAll(data);

assert.deepEqual(Array.from(set), Array.from(new Set(expected)))
```

and, voilà, the expected order is achieved.

The `repr` function categorizes items, assigning `1` to those starting with a digit and `0` to others. The first comparator `ORDER.ASCENDING` in the `TrueSet` creator sorts these classes, while within each class, the order is determined by the second comparator, `collator.compare`.

It's important to note that the `TrueSet` doesn't iterate over duplicate items. However, it retains the count of occurrences for each item, accessible via the method `n(item)`

```
const
    got = Array.from(set)
        .map(item => new Array(set.n(item)).fill(item))
            .flat();

assert.deepEqual(got, expected)
```